# Kickstart nvim with gruvbox incorrect highlights for Python files

Tags: python, neovim, pyright

I am switching from vim to neovim, and one of the most important requirements for me is to keep the colorscheme as similar as possible.
I am using kickstart.nvim, which provides a good starting point and I have managed to more or less understand most of what is going on.

To change the color scheme, I have used both my gruvbox.vim and also other github implementations, but all of them have the same problem.

This is what init.lua looks like in vim (left) and neovim (right). So one would think that the color scheme is working:
[vim vs neovim for lua file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTM9H.png)

However, when I try the same comparison for a Python file, this is what happens:
[vim vs neovim for python file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAbIt.png)

I though that the solution was that I had no lsp for Python, so I managed to install pyright, but that only provided comments about my code (and not very correct, as a side note), but the colors were still the same.

So know I have no idea how to continue or what to try next.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `vim.o.hlsearch = true` is set to true